# Upload file to server using js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Good day Gurus! I just want to ask how to upload a file using js. I need to copy the file a user selected, from the file upload dialog, to the server. I wonder if it can be done through js. If not, is there a way to upload a file to the server without using fileUpload tool from the toolbox.? Any suggestion or advice is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually there are some client side upload tools such as ajax file upload toolkit, qq file uploader etc. try do some research.. Just curious.. Why not use asp.net file upload??

Comment: @User2012384 Because I cannot access fileupload on my webservice. My BLL is on the webservice and not on the .cs of the aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case other people would need something like this without using other tool. I'll attach here the link of the site that helped me solved the problem. Hope it helps. Thanks.
Cheers. :)

[Ajaxfileupload](http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2011/12/async-file-upload-with-jquery-and.html)

Answer (score 1):

U can use some upload tools such as Uploadify.It's a Jquery tools that upload a file in Ajax.

Comment: I saw uploadify but it is using a php and flash. Is there any other tool you can suggest? thanks again.